# .htaccess Pretty URL not displaying correctly with redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure a dynamic mod rewrite rule in my .htaccess file using mod_rewrite.  I am very close to figuring this out.  I am trying to get URLs like these:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?service=14&title=events
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?service=48&title=planning
```

To automatically be rewritten to these:

```
http://www.mysite.com/service/14/events
http://www.mysite.com/service/48/planning
```

Here is my codes so far:

```
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?service=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=$1&title=$2 [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /service/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

I think there is something wrong with the last line maybe?  I'm not the best at regular expressions so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Just wanted to be clear that the pretty URLs do work.  However, the old URLs aren't redirecting and are still displaying in the browser.

I am not sure if this would be any easier but if I could get the URLs to look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/service/14/title/events
http://www.mysite.com/service/48/title/planning
```

Then that would work too.  I don't really need the second query title to be in the URL but if it's easier to leave it in there, then no big deal.

**Edit: Answered
Many thanks to all who helped contribute to the solution.  I got this for my rewrite rule:**

```
RewriteRule ^index/service/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?service=$1&title=$2
```

**Once I added 'index' it worked with both query strings. As far as the redirect goes, I edited my php script and did all the URL redirecting there, which was a lot easier. Special thanks to mkjasinski  for pointing that out.**

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: Nope. No errors.  The pretty URLs work but the old URLs aren't redirecting to them.  The page displays when navigating to the old URLs but the browser doesn't redirect to the pretty ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^service/([0-9]+?)?/([a-zA-Z\-]+?)$ index.php?service=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]
```

and if I have run: `http://localhost/service/12/This-is-text` in `$_GET` in `index.php`:

```
array (size=2)
  'service' => string '12' (length=2)
  'title' => string 'This-is-text' (length=12)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your code and just like mine the pretty URL works. However, when I try to navigate to the page using the old URL's it doesn't redirect to the new pretty ones.  Sorry I probably should have been more clear.

Comment: @kyzer1978 links must be built on the side of the application, if you want to redirect any link then you will get 2x requests.

Comment: I actually just realized that. I may just rewrite the code in my application then. Bummer, that's going to be a ton of work!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use special holders ($1,$2...) from previous rewrite rules into rewritecond.

change your code to:

```
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?service=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (?:^|&)service=([0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (?:^|&)title=([a-z]+)(&|$) [NC]   
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /service/%1/%3? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think we're almost there.  The old URLs are redirecting but now they are going to the wrong pretty url.  They're all redirecting here: `http://www.mysite.com/service//`  The query strings aren't carrying over to the new URLs.

Comment: Getting even closer now. The second query string is carrying over in the rewrite but not the first.  I'm getting this `http://www.mysite.com/service/events` or this `http://www.mysite.com/service/planning` The first query value still isn't carrying over to the new URLs.